# Trying to get drop down menu to align to the right

Tags: css, menu, navigation, alignment, dropdown

Still pretty new to css and I need a hand.
I have this site: https://nuebar.com/ and it has drop downs under hair, about etc…
I need to get the dropdowns aligning to the right edge of the menu item instead of the left.

Dropdowns are currently absolutely positioned but I'm unable to use this to get them aligned how I want them to be.

Would love some insight on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown menu css add for right:0; and parent li css add postion:relative; Below mentioned css code add and check.

```
.DropdownMenu{right:0;}
.HorizontalList__Item{position:relative;}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! worked a treat. Now I want the dropdown to start below the thin white line, would the best way to do this be setting the 
.DropdownMenu { top:77px} ? or os there a better way to have it calculate the position based on the height of the header?